# How to record audio and video on macos with ffmpeg?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

```
$ ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""
...
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x7fa8c24312c0] AVFoundation video devices:
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x7fa8c24312c0] [0] FaceTime HD Camera
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x7fa8c24312c0] [1] Capture screen 0
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x7fa8c24312c0] AVFoundation audio devices:
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x7fa8c24312c0] [0] MacBook Pro Microphone
```

These are my audio and video devices.
I'm trying to record audio from mic and video capture of screen.
However when I try to run the command I get this error:

```
$ ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "1:0"  \             
  ~/Videos/screencast.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x7fced1c315c0] Configuration of video device failed, falling back to default.
[avfoundation @ 0x7fced2009000] Selected pixel format (yuv420p) is not supported by the input device.
[avfoundation @ 0x7fced2009000] Supported pixel formats:
[avfoundation @ 0x7fced2009000]   uyvy422
[avfoundation @ 0x7fced2009000]   yuyv422
[avfoundation @ 0x7fced2009000]   nv12
[avfoundation @ 0x7fced2009000]   0rgb
[avfoundation @ 0x7fced2009000]   bgr0
[avfoundation @ 0x7fced2009000] Overriding selected pixel format to use uyvy422 instead.
```

Additionally I'd like to capture camera in lower right. This is how I do it on Linux, but the basics don't even work on MacOS.

```
screencap() {
  file=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S`
  ffmpeg -f alsa -i pulse -f x11grab -thread_queue_size 64 -i :0.0 \
  -video_size 384x216 -i /dev/video0 \
        -filter_complex 'overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h' \
  -r 60 -preset ultrafast ~/Videos/screencast-${file}.mp4
}
```

Comment: The `screencap` function has the wrong video index.

Comment: Does `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "1:0" ~/Videos/screencast.mp4` actually fail? You didn't include the **complete** log.

Comment: As shared by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56380933/5625547), that error is caused by `avfoundation` and can be ignored. Unfortunately, the command hangs on my machine(mb). Recording audio isn't that hard, but when I want to combine with video, they all 'hang'.

Comment: It just hangs. There is no other output.

Comment: Try a ffmpeg build from the git master branch before doing anything else. I'm guessing you use Homebrew. Use the `--HEAD` option.

Comment: What happens if you try to record video without sound, or sound without video? I mean `-i "1:none"` or `-i "none:0"`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sound without video is fine, video without sound gives same issue as OP.

Comment: Does this list the possible resolution/framerates correctly for camera? ` `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "0" out.mpg` and for screen with `-i "1"`

Comment: Building with `--HEAD` doesn't make any difference, Still just hangs with "0:1"

Answer (score 0):

After playing with FFMPEG to record my MacOs screen, I've always received the same error before FFMPEG would hang:

> Configuration of video device failed, falling back to default.

Finally, I've found the solution that worked for me.

The problem was caused by **insufficient permissions** on the [Screen Recording](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384228/how-do-i-configure-screen-recording-permission-on-macos-catalina) setting.

After adding [iterm](/questions/tagged/iterm) (or any other terminal application) to the allowed apps, the following FFMPEG command worked as expected:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "2:0" output.mkv
```

<sup>Don't forget to edit the screen/audio index</sup>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a same error:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "1:0" -pix_fmt uyvy422 screencast.mp4
ffmpeg version N-95190-gf66458cfc7 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
  configuration:
  libavutil      56. 35.100 / 56. 35.100
  libavcodec     58. 59.101 / 58. 59.101
  libavformat    58. 33.100 / 58. 33.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 61.100 /  7. 61.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
objc[90863]: class `NSKVONotifying_AVCaptureScreenInput' not linked into application
objc[90863]: class `NSKVONotifying_AVCaptureScreenInput' not linked into application
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x7f788c704ac0] Configuration of video device failed, falling back to default.
[avfoundation @ 0x7f788c809c00] Selected pixel format (yuv420p) is not supported by the input device.
[avfoundation @ 0x7f788c809c00] Supported pixel formats:
[avfoundation @ 0x7f788c809c00]   uyvy422
[avfoundation @ 0x7f788c809c00]   yuyv422
[avfoundation @ 0x7f788c809c00]   nv12
[avfoundation @ 0x7f788c809c00]   0rgb
[avfoundation @ 0x7f788c809c00]   bgr0
[avfoundation @ 0x7f788c809c00] Overriding selected pixel format to use uyvy422 instead.
[avfoundation @ 0x7f788c809c00] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, avfoundation, from '1:0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 883477.619167, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (UYVY / 0x59565955), uyvy422, 2880x1800, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_f32le, 44100 Hz, mono, flt, 1411 kb/s
Stream mapping:
```

add params: `-r`

This command is worked for me:

`ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "1:0" -r 30 ~/Desktop/demo.mp4`